# Is there an image dataset where each picture contains only one object？

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, dataset, artificial-intelligence, image-classification

I would like a dataset of images where each picture contains one object, similar to CIFAR-10, but with higher resolution.

CIFAR10 and CIFAR100 are good expamples because they only contains one object, but their resolution is not enough.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.